# Texstudio does not show error

Tags: compiling, texstudio

For some reason my Texstudio stopped showing error messages. Instead the compiling never stops now. For example, for the following code

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\fdasfasffasfasfaghdahhykyuk

\end{document}
```

It used to stop compiling and show error message something like *unknown command \fdasfasffasfasfaghdahhykyuk on line 17*  but now it just freezes while compiling.

Comment: Are you saying that you can see the tabs "Messages" "Log" "preview" ... but that nothing is showing in those tabs? What if you compile without Texstudio? Is the compilation actually shown as starting? What happens if you go Menu>View Log. Is there a *.log file in the file with the .tex you are compiling?

Comment: Also -- Is the option "show log in case of compile error" checked? (in build options) - also in build options additional search paths for log file should be blank (probably irrelevant) and perhaps also tick "show messages when starting compiling". For debugging you may also want to set verbose output by Enable verbose output by setting Configure -> Build -> Show stdout to "Always" (need to have advanced options enabled for this). Also try interaction=nonstopmode in the command.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Yes I see all the tabs and nothing is showing there. If I compile with Texworks, I do get 

! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \fdasfasffasfasfaghdahhykyuk

In Texstudio, the compilation is shown as started. The *.log file is created, but it is empty.

The option "show log in case of compile error" is checked.

Comment: 'Configure -> Build -> Show stdout to "Always"' - this really helped, the output is now much longer but it shows where the error is if there is one. Compiling still doesn't stop however, but at least I can see where the error is and stop the compiling manually.