# Add a matlab script(m.file) into Latex: error with text-overflow ( edit 2)

Tags: pdf, texstudio, matlab

I am trying to add an appendix with Matlab scripts in my thesis. I have used [the post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document) about it here.

In my main.tex I have added:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
....

\part*{Appendices}
\chapter{Matlab scripts}
\input{matlab_scripts.tex}
\end{document}
```

then in matlab_scripts.tex ( appendix file):

```
\section{Realisation the  algorithm 1}
\begin{filecontents*}{ algorithm.m}
    function  [a,b] = algorithm(c,d) 
    % matlab script of the function

\end{filecontents*}

\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting{algorithm.m}
```

I am using TexStudio and it doesn't build me pdf file without giving an error. Without this appendix, it works perfectly. Where Have I mistaken?
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I have fixed the error below as:

```
\section{Realisation the  algorithm 1}
\begin{filecontents*}{ algorithm.m}
    function  [a,b] = algorithm(c,d) 
    % matlab script of the function

\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting{algorithm.m}
```

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! Which error message do you get exactly?

Comment: Maybe there are errors, but they are hidden. Could you try some of the suggestions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472237/texstudio-does-not-show-error?

Comment: @Marijn I have found there is an error with MiKTeX. can it be a reason?

Comment: It can definitely be a reason. What does the error say?

Comment: @Marijn I have added the screenshot in the question-post

Comment: And what is the contents of the log file that the error refers to (`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log`)?

Comment: @Marijn thank you for helping I have fixed it

Comment: Ok, good that you fixed it. Can you say how you solved it, in a comment or in an answer? That might help future visitors to this page that have the same problem.